# Chosen operation is not enabled

Tags: borland-together

I am using borland together I have configured client license and server license.
But I am getting error message

> Choosen operation is not enabled

step:
1. open Together IDE
2. Right Click on project choose "select on diagram"

What can be cause of this error message?

Thanks